# HTML element for inserting source code styled text

Tags: html

What is the `HTML` element that one can use in order to insert source code styled text in the page display?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I missing something? The tags < code > or < pre > might serve you purpose.

Answer (score 1):

`<tt>text</tt>` will give you a fixed-width font. Wrapping this inside `<pre></pre>` will make formatting be preserved. For example, `<pre><tt>code here</tt></pre>`. You will still need to use html codes for characters such as `<` and `>` (`&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively).